# Is it safe if I turn all my security rules of firebase storage to read and write by all?

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have been trying for quite some time to develop an authentication system using firebase/auth, however this has yielded unsatisfactory results and I have noticed then whenever I log a user in the website, then I access the website from another device I can see all the data of the previous user, without needing to logIn at all. I have researched online on how to solve this however even after having done everything the firebase docs are saying, I still encounter the same problem. I can't leave it like this since it is of course a HUGE security risk. So I took the matters to my own hands and created an authentication system with json-web-tokens, this works very well, however due to my configurations of the firebase storage security rules It is impossible for me to access the data since I am not logged in with firebase/auth.

I have done my best not to show any links or configuration to my account in firebase, all images are fetched and converted to base64 in the server-side then later rendered on the page, so if I keep my firebase configurations hidden and I dont show any firebase storage links on my website is it safe for me to allow read and write without checking for the user to have been logged in using firebase/auth

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be very dangerous.
To find your configuration is easily done, since they need to be public for your connection to even work on your frontend.

If someone wants to find your config, they can. This is why security rules are very important and you should **not** allow everyone to access your database.

**Based on your current security rules:**
If someone gain access of your config, They can simply register an account and then delete your entire database with a few lines of code

If you only communicate with Firebase via a service account on a server. i.e. you are not using the web SDK, you can disable it like this:

Go to **Firebase console > Project settings > General**
At the bottom of the page you will see your active **web apps**.
Select the on you want to disable and choose **Remove this app**

Now noone can access your app via the web SDK

Comment: Well I don't see how that can happen since my configuration codes are saved in my environment variables that nobody can really access, again no information whatsoever is leaked in my frontend about my database all of it is server-side.

Comment: If you dont have it on your frontend, there's no need for security rules att since you can't use the Firebase SDK Client. I would recommend turning the web SDK off completetly in that case

Comment: I havent use my web SDK at all, however I havent done anything to turn it off completely, if you know an article that shows that please tell me. Thank your for your response. Wish you the best bo!

Comment: Updated my answer on how you can disable your web sdk

Answer (score 0):

If all access to the files in Cloud Storage comes from the Node.js SDK, it bypasses the security rules that you set anyway. So in that case, you might as well disallow all access:

```
allow read, write: if false;
```